# Tag synonym redirect broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-synonyms, redirection

Trying to query the user list for the [win32] tag at https://stackoverflow.com/tags/win32/topusers redirects to https://stackoverflow.com/tags/winapi/users.  Page not found.  I guess that should be topusers, not users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, this is the 3rd glitch with that rename, sorted in dev will be deployed either today or tomorrow